# Input changes to readonly with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a form allowing my user to fill information about a room booking.

https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/363533/

Problem are the following:

- When I select the `Special Summer` price in the dropdown, and a select back `Custom price`, the `BIL_Rate` input stays at `readonly`.
- When I'm into `BIL_Rate` input and want to pass to another input with `tab`, after 3 tabs, it will change the next `BIL_Rate` input to readonly.

What I'm missing here please ?

```
$("select[name='BIL_RateId[]'], input[name='BIL_Rate[]']").on('change keyup', function() {

        var tagname = this.tagName;
        var select = $(this).closest("tr").find('select[name="BIL_RateId[]"] :selected');
        var input = $(this).closest("tr").find('input[name="BIL_Rate[]"]');

        if(tagname == 'SELECT') {
            var name = select.attr('data-name');
            var description = select.attr('data-description');
            var rate = select.attr('data-rate');

            if(select.selectedIndex == 0) { input.val(rate).prop('readonly', false); }
            else { input.val(rate).prop('readonly', true); }

        }
        if(tagname == 'INPUT') {
            var name = '';
            var description = '';
            var rate = input.val();
        }

        var taxes = $('#accomodation_taxes_sum').val();

        var BIL_Taxes = parseFloat(rate) * taxes / 100;
        var BIL_Total = parseFloat(rate) + BIL_Taxes;

        $(this).closest("tr").find("input[name='BIL_Taxes[]']").val(BIL_Taxes);
        $(this).closest("tr").find("input[name='BIL_Total[]']").val(BIL_Total);
    });
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're checking `select.selectedIndex == 0`, but, `select` is not the SELECT element, but the OPTION element.

You should change `select.selectedIndex == 0` to `$(this)[0].selectedIndex === 0` or `$(this).prop('selectedIndex') === 0`

Answer (score 0):

In your fiddle `select.selectedIndex` is undefined. I notice you have set values in your select so change.

```
if(select.selectedIndex == 0)
```

To

```
if($(select).val() === "0")
```